# How do I make twig variables available in node.html.twig accessible in my html.html.twig?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I have a boolean field on my Content Type called 'field_bootstrap'. I have some twig logic in my node.html.twig file that, if the field is set to true, includes Bootstrap via HTML inclusion.

What I need is the ability to use my {{ node.field_bootstrap }} logic in the html.html.twig template, instead of the node-level template. This would allow me to reference Bootstrap's CDNs properly in my document's head, rather than its current position in the middle of body.

I assume I need to build a preprocess in mytheme.theme to make something like {{ custom_twig_variable }} available for use in html.html.twig but I'm a little lost on how to complete this :)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: It sounds like what you should do is put this in the node preprocess hook instead and attach the library definition containing the bootstrap asset(s) you’re trying to load. hook page attachments alter would work too. See the docs pages about attaching JS and CSS to Drupal, there are a few ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Kevin is right, creating a library and then attaching it is the better approach for this.

**theme-name.theme**

```
THEME_NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->field_bootstrap->value) { // checks boolean is true
     $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'theme-name/bootstrap-files';
  }
}
```

**theme-name.libraries.yml**

```
bootstrap-files:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/boostrap.css: {}
  js:
    js/boostrap.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
```

and you'll have to put the bootstrap css and js files inside the /css and /js folders of your theme.

---

### Better Yet

Install [Bootstrap Library](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_library) module.

**theme-name.theme**

```
THEME_NAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('bootstrap_library')) {
    $node = $variables['node'];
    if ($node->field_bootstrap->value) { // checks boolean is true
       $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'bootstrap_library/bootstrap-cdn';
    }
  }
}
```